# d3 minimum arc width

Tags: javascript, d3.js, donut-chart

I'm trying to make an interactive donut chart using d3 and am running in to an issue with certain datasets where the donut chart arc slices are too small reliably click on them for interactivity.

Example:

[image]

According some UX things I've read 44px is the desired "normal" touch size for most elements on a mobile device.

Is there any way to pad the data scale with d3 in order to ensure my slices start at a given minimum width so they are big enough to click?

Comment: One of my ideas is just figuring out how many pixels the width of the chart takes, then figure out how much that translates in to % then shift percents by weight accordingly, but unsure if this is a valid approach

Comment: Am I getting this right: you want to sacrifice accuracy for usability?

Comment: @tr3online you shouldn't do that. This is what we call "*lying with data"*.

Comment: I'm not wanting to "lie" with the data, just wondering if there's a way to normalize it somehow so slices are clickable.

Comment: @tr3online don't get me wrong, I mean no harm, but this is *lying*: just the other day, for instance, a user asked how to show a small bar if the bigger bar had a value of 10,000,000 and the small bar had a value of 5. It's simply impossible, the small bar have to be invisible. If you want to be accurate, the bars **have to be proportional**. The same goes for your donut chart. If the size of the slices don't depend on the data, this is *"lying"*.

Comment: One solution might be to use some kind of [fisheye](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) zoom-on-hover, although I reckon this would be quite hard to implement for a pie/donut chart and, thus, not worth the effort. Furthermore, it will not be suitable if you are targeting touch devices. FWIW, I think you should consider abandoning the donut chart altogether: this chart type ranks amongst the least liked ones and has serious [drawbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misleading_graph). Try looking for a chart which allows the use of e.g. logarithmic scales or an axis break.  @Gerardo